# Cakephp3, elasticsearch datasource, and elasticsearch version

Tags: php, elasticsearch, cakephp-3.x

I'm in version hell.
I'm using CakePHP 3.3.12 and just installed the latest version of ElasticSearch (5.2.2).
I then installed the ElasticSearch datasource (which is pretty clever IMO). 
I can index documents to ES, but I can't get a filter query working.

Digging deeper, the ElasticSearch datasource uses the Elastica library, which is an ElasticSearch PHP library.

Cake's ES datasource requires Elastica version ~2.2 from Composer; from Elastica's repository that would be 2.3.1 (Oct 2015), which is only compatible with ES V1.7.3

Since then, Elastica has released V3.1.1 (Mar 2016) compatible with ES2.X, and then V5.X (Dec 16) which is compatible with ES V5.X.

AFAICS the latest CakePHP ES code is only compatible with ES at least 2 major versions old.

One of the changes made from ES1.X to ES2.X is the removal of the distinction between QUERY and FILTER, and I think that's why the generated queries are choking.

So I guess my question is, what's my best option?
- Try to install ES1.7 (ugh)
- Find another library (suggestions?)
- Try to hack some upgrades myself
- Bypass CakePHP's datasource abstraction and go right to ES

Comment: Have you tried [**the `1.0` branch**](https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search/tree/1.0) which [**is said to be compatible**](https://github.com/cakephp/elastic-search/issues/116) with ES5?

Comment: I didn't see that (and I uncovered every other version in the triad...) Thanks for that.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem right now! I will look around, and let you know what I end up coming up with :)

Comment: I used the query-should branch of the elastic addin. This has not yet been packaged in composer, so I needed to install it myself. It uses a later version of elastica, and more importantly, uses a bool query as its core querying strategy, which is the correct approach for ES2+. Works like a charm, although I had to work around a bit to integrate a constant_score wrapper. Hopefully they'll coordinate a proper release soon